# Como conseguir o hacer claves ssh dinamicas entre dos maquinas

Tags: linux, ssh

Tengo 2 maquinas que se ejecutan scripts (.sh) de forma remota a la contraria , mediante ssh , por lo que necesito utilizar ssh keys.

Posteriormente dependiendo de la situacion , mi sistema, formado por ambas maquinas (2), se cambian las ips's (mi sistema es algo asi como un cluster-backup)(si una cae la otra replica la conf de red de la contraria).

En resumen, mi probelma es que si A con IP originalmente 192...3 y B con IP 192...4 se intercambian , es decir B pasa a tener la IP 192...3 , (en este caso A tendra la 192...4 y estara up) , al haber cambiado de ip's , no puedo ejecutar remotamente esos scritps a la contraria , dado que las ips no coinciden con las ips asociadas a las keys.
En otras palabras obtengo este error `Host key verification failed.`

Alguna sugerencia de como "resetear dichas claves y hacerlas dinamicas?" mediante un script .sh. (o editar la conf para poder cambiar esas ips a las que se asocian las claves?)

Pense en eliminar las ips de known_hosts y luego hacer algo como `ssh-copy-id root@192...` pero claro necesitaria ingresar la contraseña y no se como hacerlo , de forma automatizada mendiante un script.

Answer (score 2):

Lo resolvi utilizando `ssh-keyscan -H $IP >/root/.ssh/known_hosts`

Answer (score 1):

Y si creas la llave ssh para los usuarios dentro de un grupo y agregas ambas maquinas en ese grupo, para hacer esto primero deberias modificar el `sshd_config` y usar la directiva `AllowGroups groupName` y ahora para actualizar la configuracion reinicias el servicio ssh `service ssh restart`

Ahora para que un usuario reciba los " permisos " como tal agregas un usuario 
`useradd -G grupo1 -d /home/usuario4 -m -s /bin/bash usuario4`
Tambien podrias aplicarlo a un grupo ya existente
y finalmente para acceder debes hacer la prueba como tal de acceso, si funciona en horabuena

Creditos: Google.com :V